# Simple Request mapping not working, Beginners in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am beginner in spring mvc i have 2 jsp :-
1. Webcontent/index.jsp : This works fine . The index file has a hyperlinked text like :-

```
      <a href="hello.html" rel="nofollow">Say Hello</a>
```

1. WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp : which displays following in body

   ```
        ${message}
   ```

Project Container is as follows :-

```
 @Controller
  public class HelloWorldContainer {

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Following is WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml file :-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml :-

```
 <context:component-scan
    base-package="org.explorear.ar" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My Problem :-
When i run this project on tomcat server from the eclipse the index file shows up 
perfectly fine. But as the text in index file is hyperlinked to hello.html i keep getting 
Http Status 404.

Comment: please turn on debug level logging and show us exactly what is the source of 404. Without the logs, its all just guesses :)

Comment: Please check the server if it is started properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the whole page name at this line

return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp", "message", message);

And you are using ViewResolver in which you are suffixing your return value with .jsp . So in my suggestion use this

return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);

Comment: Done that... i am being navigated to http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/hello.html but still http status 404

Comment: you are using hello.jsp but in your reference you are using hello.html?you are using jsp page and calling html page in reference link?change it to hello.jsp

Comment: Use this as servlet mapping

`<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: use this in your spring-servlet.xml


`<context:component-scan base-package="your base package" />
<bean
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix">
  <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
 </property>
 <property name="suffix">
  <value>.jsp</value>
 </property>
</bean>`

Place your all jsp files inside /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder

Comment: again no luck. I have used this tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but I think

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

and context-param needs to be provided in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is how you web.xml should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>  
  <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>  
</session-config> 
</web-app>
```